# How to get the type of an object

Tags: data-types

I'm looking for a way to get the type of an object:

```
TypeOf["x"] -> String
TypeOf[1] -> Integer
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: You need the function `Head`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Example:**

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
integer = 1;
real = 0.1;

Head @ list
Head @ integer
Head @ real
```

**Output:**

```
List

Integer

Real
```

**Reference**

[Head](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html)

Answer (score 9):

(Post adapted after comments.)

*Mathematica* 10 introduced a new type system local to `Dataset`, that's used like this:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]
DeduceType[{1, Sqrt[2], "test", {1, Sqrt[2], 3}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this type system a type is not the same as `Head[expr]`. In this framework the head of an atomic value is instead retrieved by `TypeAtoms`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But yes, for what you want to do you still need `Head`.

Comment: `DeduceType` is still undocumented. What are actual use cases for this new type system?

Comment: This new type system serves primarily `Dataset`. It is not on the same fundamental level as Mathematica's core "type system", of which `Head` is part. It has a status of specific type system used by one or several application modules internally, and has no meaning in a more general context of fundamental Mathematica language / building blocks.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov So far it seems that it is mostly useful for debugging problems with `Dataset`, WReach has invoked it in several of his answers to explain different unintuitive behaviors.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It is true, but within this framework they refer to `Integer`, `Real` etc. as type atoms, not as types. So whether it is intentional or not they have introduced a new terminology for these labels. Yes, this is nitpicking. I see this as an opportunity to mention `TypeSystem` to readers who may not know about it.

Comment: Each module is free to define its own notion of types, for its own purposes. For example, `Compile` also has a type system, which is different from either the new `TypeSystem` or the core Mathematica type system. Both `Compile`'s type system and the new `TypeSystem` are incomplete - there are types they can't describe (but core Mathematica can). I agree that it is good to mention these, but the question about types in Mathematica *in general* has a clear and unique answer, and that answer is  - atoms and normal expressions, where heads of expressions one may interpret as non-atomic types.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin ok, thank you for explaining. I made some adjustments to take this into account.

Comment: Looks better now, but if I were answering, I'd probably make two sections, and make the actual answer (`Head`) coming first, and then have a second section with details on other existing more specialized type systems.